# How to resize the height when reduce width?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, responsive-design, graphael

In raphael responsive function working very well, unfortunately height doesn't decrease when resize width in **safari** browser. especially in mobile browser :(

Rapheal code

```
var svgWidth = 480;
var svgHeight = 300;
var patient02 = new Raphael('patient02-mobile', svgWidth, svgHeight);
patient02.setSize('100%',0);
patient02.setViewBox(-30, 0, svgWidth, svgHeight, false); //false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ta8mR/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your between your `<head>` tags...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Although, I've always found this to be a problem in mobile devices. It will use the greatest height and the greatest width between both landscape and portrait modes. Sometimes though, just one or the other...